# AWS remove files in S3 using CodeBuild in CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

How can I remove unwanted files in an **S3 bucket** as the output of a pipeline in **CodePipeline**, using **CodeBuild**'s `buildspec.yml` file?

For example:

The `build` folder of a GitHub repo is put in the designated S3 bucket so the bucket can be used as a static website.

I pushed a file earlier to the bucket which I don't need anymore. How do I use the `buildspec.yml` file to "clean" the bucket before pushing the artifacts of my pipeline to the bucket?

An example `buildspec.yml` file:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - mkdir build-output
      - find . -type d -name public -exec cp -R {} build-output \;
      - find . -mindepth 1 -name build-output -prune -o -exec rm -rf {} +
  post_build:
    commands:
      - mv build-output/**/* ./
      - mv build-output/* ./
      - rm -R build-output
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```

Should the command:

```
rm -rf *
```

in `build` phase like this?

```
build:

commands:
  - aws s3 rm s3://mybucket/ --recursive
```

And how do I reference the right bucket instead of hardcoding the name in the file?

Comment: Do you need to remove unnecessary files from the bucket every time or is it just a one-off operation?

Comment: I don't have to but if the build changes often, I don't want to leave too many unused files in prod so I think it's best to "clean" the bucket every time the artefacts are pushed to it. Just my thought, I'm not sure if you and the others would do the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To delete the files in the S3 bucket, you can use the `aws s3 rm --recursive` command as you already alluded to.

You can pass in the bucket name from the pipeline to CodeBuild by setting it in the environment variable.

```
ArtifactsBucket:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  Properties:
    BucketName: my-artifacts

CodeBuildProject:
  Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
  Properties:
    Environment:
      EnvironmentVariables:
          - Name: ARTIFACTS_BUCKET
            Value: !Ref ArtifactsBucket
            Type: PLAINTEXT
```

In the buildspec, you can then refer to the `ARTIFACTS_BUCKET` env var, for example:

```
build:
  commands:
    - aws s3 rm --recursive "s3://${ARTIFACTS_BUCKET}/"
```

An alternative approach you could take is to declare [lifecycle management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) on  the bucket. For example, you can say "delete all objects after 30 days" like so:

```
ArtifactsBucket:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  Properties:
    BucketName: my-artifacts
    LifecycleConfiguration:
      Rules:
        - ExpirationInDays: 30
          Id: Expire objects in 30 days
          Status: Enabled
```

Comment: just a note you must provide s3 access in a policy attached to the codebuild service role. the minimum you need is s3 read (list objects) and write (delete objects) and then give it access to <your-bucket>/* (or some specific sub directory as needed)

Comment: Can this be done in CodePipeline console?  I tried adding `!Ref artifactStore` because that's the name I see in the JSON from `aws codepipeline get-pipeline`.  But this variable is passed literally without translation.

Comment: @vampiire I'm on the same boat, how do you attach these policies to give write permissions?